# Maven is not downloading , correct version jar

Tags: spring, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I am new to maven & stuck with a problem . My project is getting build with maven , but its downloading different version jar ( Spring core 2.5.6.SEC03.jar) , although i have specified 3.1.1 version in POM.xml.

Does Maven refer any other place/configuration file while downloading jars?

I am using Maven3, my Pom.XML look like

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>             
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Its downloading Spring Tx, JDBC ,JMS correctly , but i am getting Spring Aop, core, beans, context , web with Version "2.5.6 SEC03". these five jar are not changing at all,even if i upgrade/ downgrade the version in Pom.

I am not sure what could be the cause, i have tried deleting repositry & downloading again . Any help will be great
Thanks
Sonia

Comment: You can use the maven dependency tree plugin `mvn -Dverbose=true dependency:tree` to see which component requires the 2.5.6 SEC03 Version of Spring core.

Comment: is that the full pom? I just tested this and there is no other Spring Dependencies other than the versions you use.

Comment: No its just a snippet from Pom. I found one issue here, its says 407 error, for proxy authentication. Trying to change proxy settings, but still i am confused , if proxy is a issue , how it can download half of the files successfully .

Answer (score 1):

We have also faced similar issue.

Try `mvn -Dverbose=true dependency:tree` and see that which dependencies are using Spring jar version 2.5.6 SEC03. Then either delete those dependencies or exclude the Spring jar version 2.5.6 SEC03.

Hope that it will solve the problem.